# Nav between 4 divs that are inside the .content div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div .content and inside of this div I have 4 divs (content-1,content-2,content-3,content-4).

In each of this 4 divs I have two buttons to navigate between this 4 divs.

But I dont know how to do this correclty, because by default the content-1 div is the div that appears and the others are hide.

And when I click in the right button I want to show the content-2 div, but then when I click in the left button I want to return to content-1 div, but its not working like this, in content-2 div when I click to in the left button instead of show the content-1 div its showing the content-4 div, and Im not see how to do this.

I have here my example so you can undersand better: http://jsfiddle.net/1t2xfw7e/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".left").click(function() {
        $(".content-1").hide();
        $(".content-4").show();
        return false;
    });
    $(".right").click(function() {
        $(".content-1").hide();
        $(".content-2").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your issue is that there are multiple left and right classes and how they operate depends on who they belong to.  A possible solution to this might be to store the next and previous classes as data elements on your links to know which one to go to next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the divs are similiar I suppose this solution can be valid:

```
 function getCurrIndex(obj, isLeft) {
        var re = /content-([0-9])/gi
        var cDiv = re.exec($(obj).parent().prop('className'));
        if (cDiv.length == 2) {
            var cDivIndex = parseInt(cDiv[1]);
            if (isLeft == true) {
                cDivIndex -= 1;
            } else {
                cDivIndex += 1;
            }
            if (cDivIndex <= 0) {
                cDivIndex = 4;
            } else {
                if (cDivIndex >= 4) {
                    cDivIndex = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return cDivIndex;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".left").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().hide();
            $(".content-" + getCurrIndex(this, true)).show();
            return false;
        });
        $(".right").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().hide();
            $(".content-" + getCurrIndex(this, false)).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the html-markup. (This works, but is not optimal or complete. It's just to show you another way to do it):

[JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1t2xfw7e/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content a").on("click", function(e){

        if (e.target.className=="right") {
            $(this).parent().next().show();
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
        else if (e.target.className=="left") {
            $(this).parent().prev().show();
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigate").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var $this = $(this);
        
        //hide this one
        $this.parent().hide();
        //show the one that has the matching class from the data element.
        $('.'+ $this.data('show')).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="box-left">
        <div class="box-left-up">
            <h2>Test</h2>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-1">
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-4">Left</a>
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-2">Right</a>
                    <p>content 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-2">
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-1">Left</a>
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-3">Right</a>
                    <p>content 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-3">
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-2">Left</a>
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-4">Right</a>
                    <p>content 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-4">
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-3">Left</a>
                    <a class="navigate" href="#" data-show="content-1">Right</a>
                    <p>content 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pages">
                    <p>Page 1 of 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).parent().prev()` and `$(this).parent().next()` in your event handlers

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".left").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide()
        $(this).parent().prev().show();
        return false;
    });
    $(".right").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide()
        $(this).parent().next().show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/rtvn7L49/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code helps, it that according to your specs, you want to either click on left or right and show or hide content-1 or content-2.  If you want to show content-3, or content-4, then this code would get more complex.

It is no problem that you are using css class selectors that return multiple "nodes", despite a comment to this post.

```
$(".left").click(function () {
    $(".content-2").hide();
    $(".content-1").show();
    return false;
});
$(".right").click(function () {
    $(".content-1").hide();
    $(".content-2").show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.